# How do I see VS solution structure?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, solution

I am returning to a Xamarin.Forms project, and when I open it in Visual Studio for Mac:

[image: About visual studio should version 17.6.3 (build 421)]

all I see in the solution explorer is:

[image: Solution explorer showing only projects, no files or dependencies.]

which shows none of the files in each project nor any dependencies.

How do I enable viewing all the components / files / directories?

Comment: how old is this project?  You shouldn't have to do anything to view it in solution explorer

Comment: @Jason it's about six months since I last looked at it.

Comment: I'm guessing your solution/project is targeting a version of .NET which you don't have an installed SDK for? Either that, or do a repair-reinstall of VS-for-Mac (BTW, VS-for-Mac was killed-off this week: https://devclass.com/2023/08/31/visual-studio-for-mac-retired-from-open-source-to-closed-source-to-dead/

Comment: @Dai The project still compiles correctly (at least iOS, I haven't tried Android).  Yes, I'm aware of the VS-for-Mac going away. They've been telegraphing it for a while.

Comment: Did you install the xamarin template? Or did you try to create a new xamarin project to check if the will appear or not?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT This is a longer-term project that used to work fine. I could see the XAML and .cs code behind files for all views. It's just with recent versions of VS that it started behaving like this.  After some work in the IDE it shows more files, but still not everything.  I suppose I could create a new project, as I need to migrate it to MAUI anyway.

Comment: You can try to report this to the visual studio community.